# Как сделать просмотр содержимого документа на странице локального сервера?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, view, doc

Всем привет, делаю учебный проект на openserver, там у меня есть загрузка текстовых файлов, и я хотел бы как нибудь организовать просмотр без скачивания этих документов на отдельных страницах, подскажите как это можно сделать? Пробовал iframes от google view, результата нет, предполагаю, что из-за локалки, но я не знаю, может есть какие то плагины или готовые решения для этого?